# mysql select query optimization of partitioned table in non-cluster environment

Tags: mysql, performance, partition

I have select query on a partitioned table with 123 million records which is taking more then 10 minutes to fetch data. My query looks like 'select * from tableName where column1='1.1.1.1' order by timestamp desc';
Table is already indexed on column1.

Any help appreciated.

(From comments)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    column1 varchar(256) NOT NULL, 
    column2 varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    column3 smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    column4 smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    timestamp bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    KEY mytable_idx (column2,timestamp,column3,column4), 
    KEY ip_addr_index (column1), 
    KEY ts_idx (timestamp)
    )  /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ((TIMESTAMP))
           (PARTITION p1498800000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1498800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
            PARTITION p1500000000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1500000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
            PARTITION p1501200000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1501200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
            PARTITION p1502400000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1502400000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
            PARTITION p1503600000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1503600000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
            PARTITION p1504800000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1504800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
            PARTITION p1506000000 VALUES  LESS THAN (1506000000) ENGINE = InnoDB
                          ) */
```

Comment: Which columns do you actually need in the query?

Comment: How do you partition the table?

Comment: Strange partition sizes -- looks like a little less than 2 weeks??

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select *
from tableName
where column1 = '1.1.1.1'
order by timestamp desc;
```

You want an index on `(column1, timestamp desc)`.  Note:  The `desc` may be ignored in earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: actually this table is having 3 index, one on timestamp, second on column1 and third on timestamp,column2,column3 & i'm using mysql 5.7

Comment: @srinivas . . . And none of those are equivalent to the index mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONing` does not intrinsically provide speed.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss whether partitioning actually *hurts* performance in your case.

```
INDEX(column1, timestamp)  -- In this order
```

is optimal whether the table is partitioned or not.  In particular, that index will work just as good for non-partitioned.  (Gordon's comment about `DESC` has no impact on performance, whether old or new version.)

With 123 million rows, you should keep an eye on datatypes.  If you have

```
column1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET utf8
```

then that ipv4_address can be improved from up-to-17 bytes to exactly 4:

```
BINARY(4)
```

with suitable conversions on `INSERT` and `SELECT`.  Making that change would also allow for CDR and other range tests, which are not possible with `VARCHAR`.  Will you need to handle IPv6?  I discuss that [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges).

How many rows match `1.1.1.1`?  Are there any `TEXT` columns?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Which Engine?  Each of those questions *may* have an impact on the "10 minutes".

It is important to understand when a "composite" index is better than a single-column index.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**after CREATE**

Replace this

```
KEY ip_addr_index (column1)
```

with

```
KEY ip_addr_index (column1, timestamp)
```

Don't create more than one future partition before it is needed.  Always have a `LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)` partition just in case.

IPv4 can live with `VARCHAR(15)`; IPv6 fits in `(39)` or `BINARY(16) after packing.

For that one query, 7 queries must be done (one per partition); the results put together, then sorted.  Without partitioning, it becomes one query, no sort (since the index is already sorted).  So, (I believe) that partitioning *slows that query down*.

When discussing performance in 123M rows, I need to see all the main queries in one sitting in order to advise.  Optimizing for one query is all to likely to de-optimize for some other.

There seems to be no reason to use `BIGINT` for `TIMESTAMP`.  `INT UNSIGNED` would save 4 bytes per row of data, plus more for the indexes.  Perhaps a total savings of 2GB of disk space.  That translates into some speedup for *some* queries.

If `timestamp` is always used in a "range", then this index `(column2,timestamp,column3,column4)` is *probably* in an inefficient order.  Please provide the query that benefits from this index so I can further elaborate.

Comment: Out put from show create table                                                                            CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `column1` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `column3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column4` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `mytable_idx` (`column2`,`timestamp`,`column3`,`column4`),
  KEY `ip_addr_index` (`column1`),
  KEY `ts_idx` (`timestamp`)
)

Comment: /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ((TIMESTAMP))
(PARTITION p1498800000 VALUES LESS THAN (1498800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1500000000 VALUES LESS THAN (1500000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1501200000 VALUES LESS THAN (1501200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1502400000 VALUES LESS THAN (1502400000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1503600000 VALUES LESS THAN (1503600000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1504800000 VALUES LESS THAN (1504800000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1506000000 VALUES LESS THAN (1506000000) ENGINE = InnoDB) */ |

Comment: Thanks.  I added more advice.  PS, [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) is more on partitioning.